# How can I merge 2 arrays of objects, adding the values from one key where the other keys' values are equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, a user's array of skills, with each skill being an object:

```
{skill: string, points: number}
```

The other array are skill/point objects from a specific course that I want to merge into the user's array when the user adds this course.

e.g.

User's skills:

```
[
   {skill: "JavaScript", points: 5},
   {skill: "CSS", points: 3},
   {skill: "HTML", points: 1},
   {skill: "React", points: 4}
]
```

Course skills:

```
[
   {skill: "JavaScript", points: 2},
   {skill: "GraphQL", points: 1},
   {skill: "HTML", points: 2}
]
```

Desired result of user's skills:

```
[
   {skill: "JavaScript", points: 7},
   {skill: "CSS", points: 3},
   {skill: "HTML", points: 3},
   {skill: "React", points: 4},
   {skill: "GraphQL", points: 1}
]
```

Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `courseSkills` and find the item with the corresponding `skill` property. If it exists, you can add the `points` property. Otherwise, push the item into the array.

```js
const userSkills = [{
    skill: "JavaScript",
    points: 5
  },
  {
    skill: "CSS",
    points: 3
  },
  {
    skill: "HTML",
    points: 1
  },
  {
    skill: "React",
    points: 4
  }
]

const courseSkills = [{
    skill: "JavaScript",
    points: 2
  },
  {
    skill: "GraphQL",
    points: 1
  },
  {
    skill: "HTML",
    points: 2
  }
]

courseSkills.forEach(e => {
  let found = userSkills.find(f => f.skill == e.skill);
  found ? found.points += e.points : userSkills.push(e)
})
console.log(userSkills);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
const skill = [
   {skill: "JavaScript", points: 5},
   {skill: "CSS", points: 3},
   {skill: "HTML", points: 1},
   {skill: "React", points: 4}
]

const skill2 = [
   {skill: "JavaScript", points: 2},
   {skill: "GraphQL", points: 1},
   {skill: "HTML", points: 2}
]

const merged = [...skill, ...skill2].reduce((acc,cur) => ({
    ...acc,
    [cur.skill]: acc[cur.skill] ? acc[cur.skill] + cur.points : cur.points
}), {});

// OUTPUT
// "merged": {
//     "JavaScript": 7,
//     "CSS": 3,
//     "HTML": 3,
//     "React": 4,
//     "GraphQL": 1
//   },
```

To be the same as the initial format:

```
const format = Object.entries(merged).map(([skill, points] )=> ({ skill, points }))

// OUTPUT
// "format": [
//     {
//       "skill": "JavaScript",
//       "points": 7
//     },
//     {
//       "skill": "CSS",
//       "points": 3
//     },
//     {
//       "skill": "HTML",
//       "points": 3
//     },
//     {
//       "skill": "React",
//       "points": 4
//     },
//     {
//       "skill": "GraphQL",
//       "points": 1
//     }
//   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` for this after concatenating the two arrays together. This way you can avoid overwriting one of the original arrays.

```js
const courseSkills = [
  { skill: "JavaScript", points: 2 },
  { skill: "GraphQL", points: 1 },
  { skill: "HTML", points: 2 }
]
const userSkills = [
  { skill: "JavaScript", points: 5 },
  { skill: "CSS", points: 3 },
  { skill: "HTML", points: 1 },
  { skill: "React", points: 4 }
]

const combinded = [...userSkills, ...courseSkills]
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(i => i.skill === cur.skill);
    (index === -1) ? acc.push(cur) : acc[index].points += cur.points;
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(combinded);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SamuelThoyre You're welcome. Please remember to upvote and select the best answer